# How to start with regression analysis? 10 variables; 1M samples

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

My statistics knowledge is limited, and it appears that I have a task which would benefit from regression analysis. Please direct me.

I've around 10 variables (A, B, C, ...) which *might* be related to X. Most of the variables and X are floats. One variable is binary, and another is categorical (on a nominal scale). I have to find the relationship between the variables and X, in order to predict X for samples where I don't have its value (I guess that's what regression analysis is, and since I have multiple variables that's multiple regression).

First, I need to find which of these variables are actually relevant (related to X). How do I do that? Do I have to compute the correlation of each with X?

Second, how can I determine the relationship, to calculate X?

I have 1 million samples. I can use a random subset for training (1%?), and test the developed method on the rest. I have no preference on the method, it can be linear or non-linear.

I know some Python and Numpy/Scipy if it helps.

I understand that this is a general question, but regression seems to be a huge field, and I have no idea where to start. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m not really equipped to answer your question, but I think if you answer these two questions, it might help narrow down your search for an answer. (1) Is the goal purely to predict X or would you also like to draw some sort of conclusions about how your 10 variables are related to X? (2) Do you have any insight based on previous knowledge about how your 10 variables might be related to X?

Comment: This is a very general question. Try [this book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) for a good introduction; chapters 1-3 in particular for getting started, and chapters 5 and 6 for validation strategies and selecting among your predictor variables.

Comment: @Angela: (1) the goal is two fold, both to predict X and to draw conclusions about how these 10 variables are related to X. (2) I have no insight, there is no previous research on this.

Comment: @EdM: Thanks. I downloaded the book. Yeah, it's a general question, but I don't even know from where to start. I hope the book will help me to start.

Comment: It's hard to think of a better place to start. Taking the time to learn about the good approaches taught in this book will make your work on this project more reliable and stay with you when you go on to other projects.

Comment: Note that you don't *need* to find "relevant" predictors first: you can leave it to the regression to tell you exactly how relevant each is. Examining the correlation between the response & each predictor to decide which to include is called "univariate screening" & isn't generally a good idea. See Babyak (2004), "What you see may not be what you get: a brief, nontechnical introduction to overfitting in regression-type models", *Psychosomatic Medicine*, **66**, pp 411–421, though your large sample size suggests you shouldn't have to worry too much.

Comment: @EdM: I've read the first three chapters: the book is great. Seems exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your suggestion. Please make your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Scortchi thanks for the heads-up. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a general introduction to approaches for regression or classification, [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) is a great choice if you have a bit of mathematical background.

The first 3 chapters cover the essentials of what you need to get started with your linear regressions. Chapter 5 covers ways to validate your model, going beyond the simple training and validation sets you propose in the question. Chapter 6 discusses approaches to selecting among your predictors, which gets to your question about "which of these variables are actually relevant"; this is more than just examining predictors that are individually related to your outcome variable, as @Scortchi pointed out in a comment. The exercises provided for each chapter give the opportunity to test your learning as you go.

For a more advanced treatment, you can then graduate to the related book [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf).

I always keep links to both of these readily accessible on my computer.